# Do_Shortcode not working for Embed any tweet

Tags: embed, twitter

I'm trying to use Custom Field types to embed twetter using the Do_Shortcode() like this :

```
echo do_shortcode('[tweet https://twitter.com/wordpressdotcom/status/204557548249026561 ]');
```

And its not work with me after

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

In my theme.

Iam try search and found this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22524/do-shortcode-not-working-for-embed) but not work with me .

How can embed tweet in my theme

Comment: Post the callback that handles the tweet shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
<?php

  /**
   *  Shortcode look like this.
   *  [tweet url="http://www.yourwebsitename.com"] Twitter [/tweet]
  */

  add_shortcode ( "tweet" , "ease_button" );
  function ease_button( $atts, $content ) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
              "url"     => false,     
    ), $atts ));

    $url = ( $atts['url'] ) ? $atts['url'] : '#';    
    return sprintf( '<a href="%s"> %s </a>',$url, $content );
  }
?>
```

Comment: where can i add this url `https://twitter.com/wordpressdotcom/status/204557548249026561`i dont need show link of tweet, i need to show tweet content